# Do my potential customers need to understand the "meaning" of a logo, or just recognize it?

Tags: logo, shapes, designers, freelance

I'm trying to come up with a logo for a web devlopment freelance company called Two-Bit Studios. The logo concept that I came up with involves a 1 and 0 combined to make a lowercase 'b'.

To me as a developer, this makes sense in many ways.

1. "bits" are just binary digits with the only options of 1 or 0.
2. The binary representation for two is '10'
3. The 1 and 0 makes a lowercase 'b' which is the symbol for 'bit' (as well as the first letter, for extra clarity).

However, most of the people I'd be doing development work probably wouldn't know any of that, they'll probably just see a stylized 'b' which is a pretty insignificant part of "two-bit". Would this lead to a lot of misunderstanding or is the recognition of the logo more important.

(**Note:** I'm not a designer I'll be sending off my concept to someone more talented to greatly refine it, I'm just supplying the idea, this question is just about the concept of the logo).

[image]

Comment: Insert compulsory, "There are 10 types of people in the world…" joke here.

Comment: This is a great, great question!

Comment: I think the discussion is being led by the idea of bits a little too much here: "two-bit" has a very definite meaning in American English ("insignificant" or "cheap/poor quality"). Certainly used here as playful and ironic, but it should be considered as the primary meaning, regardless of the business domain.

Comment: On first look, the logo seems more like "1 bit".

Comment: I was having this *same exact* question with this logo: https://uvreatio.sirv.com/Images/Shrynk.png . The bottom part should be about compression, the top part about predictions, and it shrinks from left to right. I think the people looking at it at won't get all of it most of the time, but I still think it is interesting to look at even for people who are clueless. I think yours ticks the box as well that it is actually a nicely stylized `b` at the very least, you'll score a lot of bonus points for those that will understand (like shrynk, it relies on hearing the name).

Comment: The `0` looks more like an `o` - I'm no graphic designer, but if I were to flip the problem on its head and think of a company name from a logo, for yours I'd think of something like "1-online" or something like that. just my $0.02.

Comment: If people were "to get" meaning of the logo there wouldn't be "hidden meaning behind logos you see everyday" where Amazon and FedEx are always mentioned.

Comment: It's a bummer when you have an "idea" logo idea, and nobody "gets" it !  Unfortunately that seems to be the case here.  Working in the multinational ad agencies (in the old days when those existed!) a couple times a week someone in one department or another would think up an "idea" logo for one or the other project. Everyone glances at it and one of two things happens. Everyone says "Sure, I get it, this letter is actually shaped like a penis, and the client sells catheters! hahahaha" - or - "Nah, doesn't work".   It's a nuisance when you think up one that doesn't work!

Comment: Wait - are you a developer in the sense of a software engineer?  If so I'd honestly forget about the logo, mate!

Comment: I think that the esoteric-ness of the logo has been covered plenty by other answers so I am going to suggest that a bigger hurdle is that "two-bit" generally has a bad connotation: > The definition of two bit is someone or something that is not very good or that is poor or inferior in some way. https://www.yourdictionary.com/two-bit ---------- https://grammarist.com/usage/two-bit/ https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two-bit https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/two-bit

Comment: I feel like it's too late for a title edit, but it seems to me this Q should read "is it bad if my logo is sending mixed messages?"

Comment: @Emilie I wholeheartedly agree. I think "Is it bad if the underlying meaning behind my logo is not being conveyed" would also work. And I don't think it's too late, given the answers posted.

Answer (score 21):

Your customers don't have to understand your name. Your customers don't have to understand your logo. Your customers do have to remember both. To make it easier to remember you'll typically make a logo that relates to the name.

The most important thing though is that its memorable. Any reasoning behind it quite honestly doesn't matter.

A mentor of mine many years ago named his company 540 Interactive. The 540 was the number of times a bird he owned flapped its wings in a minute. His logo was the text 540 Interactive with a little bird perched atop it. Did anyone ever get why the bird was related? Nope! Did it matter? Nope!

The fact is if the logo makes sense to you, don't worry about whether or not anyone else gets all of the nuance behind it. If someone asks you can explain it. Making it memorable and putting it in front of customers is far more important.

Comment: And I'd bet that people ALWAYS asked "Why the bird?"  And once told, never forgot the logo.

Comment: +1 Many famous logo's meanings are not even a consideration for most customers, and some have even been lost to history. Shell is a great example of this; with their past in import/export of various antiques, oriental shells, and kerosene. Another one is the barber poles with their red, white and blue spirals, which [represent the bloodletting procedures they were historically allowed to perform.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.history.com/.amp/news/why-are-barber-poles-red-white-and-blue)

Comment: It's hard to understand from your anecdote if you think 540 was cleverly chosen... it does not sound memorable to me at all (was it 530?)

Comment: That's a totally incorrect and bad example for the problem at hand, Ryan.  Certainly, many companies have names/logos that are "whacky unrelated ideas".  That issue is utterly unrelated in any way to "idea logos" where there is a "clever" symbolic link in the logo to a meaning related to the project.

Comment: @Emilie While Shell is definitely an example of a weak link between the name of a company and what it does (now), the connection between the logo (a red and white seashell) and the name (Shell) seems pretty much on the nose to me. Though not explicitly stated, the question seems to be much more about the latter than the former.

Comment: @Jasper Oh I definitely agree that the link between the icon and the wordmark with Shell is totally descriptive. That Q's title might need an edit. It seems more like OP's asking if we understand the meaning of the logo they've designed, and not so much if people need to understand why an icon is the way it is in general.

Answer (score 9):

> Do my potential customers need to understand the “meaning” of a logo?

If a 100% understanding is not achieved graphically, at least it should have a hint of the meaning.

> Do my potential customers need to recognize my logo?

100% yes.

As in everything, I think it's about reaching a balance, if it turns in favor of one of the two options, much better for you, your company and your costumers.

---

Now:

I don't think it's very positive to disadvantage this balance towards a negative point. In the case of your logo, beyond formal errors, which has them, there's a quite important conceptual controversy that leads any potential customer not to immediately interpret its meaning.

The company is called “**TWO**-Bit Studios” and the main image perceived is a “**1**”.

Beyond the meanings, there is formally a **two** represented with a **one**.

A few years ago, quite a few, there was a stylistic tendency derived from deconstructivism that favored this type of interpretation to catch the public attention. There are examples in advertising, fashion, architecture and also in graphic design where for example a logo had some error in kerning, or alignment, or also some conceptual ambivalences. If in your case you talk about *2* and the image represents a *1* (and a 0), you are generating an ambiguity that can affect an effective result of your logo, which can be remembered for the “*pseudo*” error, but I don't think it will be interpreted.

Imagine your logo with the name below:

[image: logo+name]

There's a graphic representation of **four** elements: the **two**, the **one**, the **0** and the **bit** b:

- **4** – **2** – **1** – **0** – **b**

Maybe for a developer it might be something immediate, for a general public I don't think so.

---

I'm not a developer, but I know that among the main visual characteristics of the binary code are:

- Items repetition
- Equal distance between each component

[image]

Neither of these two features is represented to favor the shape of the letter b. Another point to increase the non-immediate interpretation.

---

Personally I think there are too many elements for something so simple. Perhaps a cleaning in the conceptual argument favors both points raised in the question:

- Do my potential customers need to understand the “meaning” of a logo?
- Do my potential customers need to recognize the logo?

Comment: Now I want that shirt!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, customers need to understand a logo, especially with a new first-contact, never-seen-this-before logo. They will — in time — recognize it after seeing it repeatedly, but it still needs to make sense for anyone looking at it for the first time. Some possible reactions looking at your "idea":

- is this really a "b"?
- does it look like a "ten"?
- where's the "2"?
- why different shades of white?
- why semi-transparent?
- why red?

It just looks more complicated then it should be, but good to hear you're sending this off to a professional who may be able to give you a new perspective. As a designer, i think there's definitely a better way to look at this.

Answer (score 4):

Okay I'll supply my short, image free, answer ... :)

No, it is not *inherently* bad if the underlying meaning of any logo is not picked up on in a conscious manner.

Logos don't have to consciously convey *anything*... it's all about subconscious interpretation. As long as the impression the logo makes is **favorable**, it makes absolutely no difference that viewers understand the representation of bits or that it's intended to convey some sort of "code" structure. None of that matters.

---

You *can't* tell me the meaning behind logo symbology such as Adidas, Pepsi, Motorola, Triple A, or even Adobe is readily apparent. It's not. People simply remember the mark and aren't typically concerned with *why* the mark is how it is.

Answer (score 3):

You're making a common novice mistake. Trying to be clever and not having the execution skills to follow through. You also don't need a symbol for such a short name, and the 1 in the symbol for a company which actually has a 2 in the name is begging for confusion.

A word mark would be the best approach, so just spell out 2-bit in Helvetica XBold and be done with it.

As a professional agency designer for 15+ years, the approach i would take is: make the brand elements representative of bits and not binary numbers. They are effectively 'on' and 'off'... so you can get creative with that idea (filled/stroked. Square/circle. Red/blue etc etc). By displaying the name clearly you'd be facilitating the viewer to be able understand any subsequent bit/binary visual references. When designers say "keep it simple" we mean minimal, legible and to the point.

Comment: so very correct man, so many people over thinking, things just lose their sense

Comment: This is (no offense to the other answers) the only valuable answer here.  Well, I guess that is offensive to the other answers!  :O

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer. Calling someone an amateur and unskilled at the beginning of an answer is not very polite though, nor is it necessary for your answer. Could you [edit] your answer to change the tone a bit and make it more welcoming to the graphic design aficionado (amateur and professional alike)?

Comment: How does this answer the question of whether or not a logo needs to be understood or just memorable?